# JQuery Mobile ListView show text on multiple lines with slider button

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a list view with jQuery Mobile and I'm trying to align listview descriptions with (slider) buttons.

I have a long description text. The problem is that I need the text to start a new line if the screen is too small (or text to long), what happens now is that the text get mixed with button.

Below is my Code

```
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
  <h1>header</h1>
   <a href="#" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="back"  rel="external" data-   iconpos="notext">Refresh</a> </div>
 <div class="content-primary" >
 <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBasic-input" data-icon="false" class="table">
<li ><a href="#">
  <div  >
    <h2 style="text-align:justify; font-size:16px; white-space:normal;"> How Do I Know if Healthcare is a Good Career Choice for Me? </h2>
    <p class="ui-li-aside">
      <select id="flip-select" name="flip-select" data-role="flipswitch" data-mini="true">
        <option>No </option>
        <option>Yes</option>
      </select>
    </p>
  </div>
  </a></li>
<li><a href="#">
  <div>
    <h2 style="text-align:justify; font-size:16px; white-space:normal;">How and Where Do I Start to Pursue a Healthcare Career? </h2>
    <p class="ui-li-aside">
      <<select name="select-choice-a" id="select-choice-a" data-native-menu="false">
     <option>Custom menu example</option>
     <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
     <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
     <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
     <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
    </select>
    </p>
  </div>
  </a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jJhMp/

#### CSS:

```
.ui-listview > li h1, .ui-listview > li h2, .ui-listview > li h3, .ui-listview > li h4, .ui-listview > li h5, .ui-listview > li h6 {
    margin: 0.45em 7em 0.45em 0 !important;
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```